# The method add(String) is undefined for type JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, eclipse

I'm trying to create a JSON Array and add names to the list. But I can't get Eclipse to simply add strings to the list. I tried looking around for answers but no luck.

```
    JSONArray listNodes = new JSONArray(); //Create a JSON array for the nodes
    listNodes.add("hi");
```

I get a red line under add saying "The method add(String) is undefined for type JSONArray"

How do I fix this?

Comment: ...And the question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you're using JSON-java for this. In that case, the correct method is `put(Object)`.

```
JSONArray listNodes = new JSONArray(); //Create a JSON array for the nodes
listNodes.put("hi");
```

Documentation: [JSONArray#put(Object)](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html#put-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Then if I had a JSON Object named "a" would I make the heading by:

a.put("nodes", listNodes);   

?

Comment: Yes. Take some time to familiarize yourself with the library. Documentation for JSONObject is here: https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

Comment: *I presume you're using JSON-java* - where does this presumption come from?